# How do I write compressed files to Google Cloud Storage using Google Cloud Dataflow?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I am trying to write Gzipped files into Google Cloud Storage buckets in a Google Dataflow program. The FAQs say that

```
Does the TextIO source and sink support compressed files, such as GZip?
Yes. Cloud Dataflow can read files compressed with gzip and bzip2.
```

Does this mean that they don't support writing of GZip files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Correct, we currently don't have built-in support for writing gzip files.
However, the [user-defined data format API](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/sources-and-sinks#creating-sinks), in particular [FileBasedSink](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/java-sdk/JavaDoc/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/io/FileBasedSink), should make it straightforward to write a sink like that yourself.

Comment: Thanks. You may want to address that [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/reading-and-writing-data#TextIO) as the document mentions that you can write to gzipped file by using withCompressionType

Comment: The relevant documentation now appears to be here: https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/text-io

Answer (score 2):

In the new Beam libraries, you can now do this much more easily:

```
PDone d = c2.apply(TextIO.write()
  .to("gs://path")
  .withWritableByteChannelFactory(FileBasedSink.CompressionType.GZIP));
```