# How to compress output file in Dataflow Java SDK?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

My pipeline stores the output data ,file, to GCS.
I would like to compress this file.
TextIO has uncompress the file which is compressed,
but I guess it does not have compress the file.
How can I compress output file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently an open [feature request](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/pull/450) for DataFlow, however the work has already been done in Beam. Once Dataflow 2.0 is released (which will be based on Beam) this should be officially supported.

That said, I have been able write compressed GZIP files by extending the [FileBasedSink](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/java-sdk/JavaDoc/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/io/FileBasedSink) class and utilizing Jeff Payne's work on this feature in Beam.

```java
public class GZIPSink<T> extends FileBasedSink<T>  {
    private final Coder<T> coder;

    GZIPSink(String baseOutputFilename, Coder<T> coder) {
        super(baseOutputFilename, ".gz");
        this.coder = coder;
    }

    @Override
    public FileBasedWriteOperation createWriteOperation(PipelineOptions pipelineOptions) {
        return new GZIPWriteOperation(this, coder);
    }

    static class GZIPWriteOperation<T> extends FileBasedSink.FileBasedWriteOperation<T> {
        private final Coder<T> coder;

        private GZIPWriteOperation(GZIPSink<T> sink, Coder<T> coder) {
            super(sink);
            this.coder = coder;
        }

        @Override
        public FileBasedWriter createWriter(PipelineOptions pipelineOptions) throws Exception {
            return new GZIPBasedWriter(this, coder);
        }
    }

    static class GZIPBasedWriter<T> extends FileBasedSink.FileBasedWriter <T> {
        private static final byte[] NEWLINE = "\n".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        private final Coder<T> coder;
        private GZIPOutputStream out;

        public GZIPBasedWriter(FileBasedWriteOperation<T> writeOperation, Coder<T> coder) {
            super(writeOperation);
            this.mimeType = MimeTypes.BINARY;
            this.coder = coder;
        }

        @Override
        protected void prepareWrite(WritableByteChannel channel) throws Exception {
            out = new GZIPOutputStream(Channels.newOutputStream(channel), true) {{
                def.setLevel(def.BEST_COMPRESSION);
            }};
        }

        @Override
        public void write(T value) throws Exception {
            coder.encode(value, out, Coder.Context.OUTER);
            out.write(NEWLINE);
        }

        @Override
        public void writeFooter() throws IOException {
            out.finish();
        }
    }
}
```

And then to actually do the write:

`aStringPCollection.apply(Write.to(new GZIPSink("gs://path/sharded-filename", StringUtf8Coder.of()));`

Comment: Link to the PR where this gets merged in Beam, because I'm limited to 2 links per post at my karma level. https://github.com/apache/beam/commit/b7b68e6fb1aafb6b4160e5dcea022bf6c802e33f

Answer (score 1):

`TextIO` only supports reading compressed files. It does not support writing files with compression.

https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/text-io#reading-from-compressed-text-files

> TextIO does not currently support writing to compressed files.

More info:

- [How do I write compressed files to Google Cloud Storage using Google Cloud Dataflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31375218/how-do-i-write-compressed-files-to-google-cloud-storage-using-google-cloud-dataf)
- [Compress files saved in Google cloud storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38858724/compress-files-saved-in-google-cloud-storage)

Answer (score 0):

As Thang mentioned this is now possible in the beam sdk version 2 by adding `.withCompression(Compression.GZIP)`:

```
// Without Compression:
pcollection.apply(TextIO.write().to("/path/to/file.txt"));

// With Compression:
pcollection.apply(TextIO.write().to("/path/to/file.txt"))
      .withSuffix(".txt")
      .withCompression(Compression.GZIP));
```

The full example given can be found [in the docs](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.6.0/)